# zsh: up-line-or-history does not work in urxvt

Tags: zsh, rxvt

`up-line-or-history` works well in gnome-terminal, but does not work after I switched to urxvt. I've tested this by explicitly calling this command in zsh (`M-x` in emacs mode). Can anyone give me a clue of why? I'm on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

`urxvt` and `gnome-terminal` send different characters when you type <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>.  You can see this using `cat -v`.  In `urxvt`, you would see `^[[A`, while `gnome-terminal` copies `xterm`, sending `^[[`;3A`.

Unless you have configured your `zsh` key bindings to take that into account, they will not work as expected.  Some workarounds are needed, because (although `zsh` can use terminfo values), `zsh` does not provide a way to use the terminal information for *modified* special keys.

Further reading:

- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys) (ncurses FAQ)
- [How can I use shift- or control-modifiers?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: For me it works whether I do `bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search` or
`bindkey "\e[A" up-line-or-beginning-search`, but I have to `source ~/.zshrc` manually each time after I enter urxvt. Do you know why?